# WMTS GetCapabilities from Geoserver provides WebMercatorGrid MatrixSet with wrong axis order

Tags: geoserver

In Geoserver, I'm fetching a WMTS capabilities document and the built-in WebMercatorGrid matrix set seems to have the axis order in northing/easting, but my understanding is that EPSG:3857 is defined by EPSG as having an axis order of easting/northing.

Here is the relevant section of the XML returned by Geoserver:

```
<TileMatrixSet>
  <ows:Identifier>WebMercatorQuad</ows:Identifier>
  <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
  <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>5.59082264028717E8</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>2.003750834E7 -2.003750834E7</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
  </TileMatrix>
  ...
</TileMatrixSet>
```

The top left corner is shown as "2.003750834E7 -2.003750834E7" but I believe it should be reversed.

This is causing problems with OpenLayers as a client (layer doesn't show up at all). The client [should be intelligent enough to detect projects with reversed axis orders](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/WMTS.js#L451) but I don't think EPSG:3857 is *supposed* to have a reversed axis order?

If I switch to the legacy "EPSG:900913" matrix set provided by Geoserver, everything works as expected.

Is this a bug in Geoserver or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Looking at the [official spec for the WebMercatorQuad tile matrix set](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-083r2/17-083r2.html#63) lists the top left corner as -20037508.3427892 20037508.3427892. This is expected and differs from the order I get from Geoserver.

Comment: Please create a bug report at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues/.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks, I've added this bug report: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10902